# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC (Trying to modify cell in Excel through PowerShell)

Tags: excel, powershell

I just recently joined an IAM team, and this month had to send out hundreds of emails to people notifying them of an account expiration (they are asked to either request for an extension or termination of the account). Thankfully, there's already a script made to do that part, but for dealing with the responses there is not. There's an excel spreadsheet where I record what is to happen to each account. I was hoping to make a script that can go through each of the responses and mark in the desired field in the spreadsheet accordingly. I've been having trouble with the part of the script where I modify the value under the desired field for the user.

I'm fairly new to PowerShell, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I already spent a few hours looking online and found quite a few possible solutions, but none of them have worked for me. A common problem is apparently using an older excel file, but it's fresh and it's Excel 2016. Another one is not having the correct file type, but I checked and that's not it either. The line of code in question is `$extend.Cells.Item($modifyCell.Cells.Row) = "$data"`.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Code:

```
# Path to .msg files
$msgDir = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test"
# Array to store results
$msgArray = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]

# Loop throuch each .msg file
Get-ChildItem "$msgDir" -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Open .msg file
        $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
        $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
        # Add .msg file Subject and Body to array        
      $msgArray.Add([pscustomobject]@{Subject=$msg.Subject;Body=$msg.Body;})
        $msg.Close(0) # Close doesn't always work, see KB2633737 -- restart ISE/PowerShell
    }

# Loop though / parse each message
ForEach ($message in $msgArray) {
    $subject = $message.subject
    $body = $message.body

    $regex = [regex] '\s*(\w*)\s*\|$'

    If ($body -match $regex) {
        $username = $body
    }
    $parse = $body | Select-String -Pattern "Please extend"
    If ($parse -eq "Please extend") {
        $data = "Y"   
    }
}

# Open Excel
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
$OpenFile = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.xlsx")

$Workbook = $OpenFile.Worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Item(1)

# Get the values for each column
$samacctname = $Worksheet.Cells | where {$_.value2 -eq "SAM Account Name"} | select -First 1
$extend = $Worksheet.Cells | where {$_.value2 -eq "Extend"} | select -First 1

# Get the values for each row in SAM Account Name
$userValues = @()
for($i=2; $samacctname.Cells.Item($i).Value2 -ne $null; $i++  ){
    $userValues += $samacctname.Cells.Item($i)
}

# Get the values where the cell value of SAM Account matches the username
$modifyCell = $userValues | where {$_.Value2 -eq $username}

# Modify the Extend cell using the username's row position
$extend.Cells.Item($modifyCell.Cells.Row) = "$data"

# Save the file
$OpenFile.Save()
```

Edit 1: I went back into my code and first tried to hard-code the data value I was trying to add to the cell, but I still got the same error. I then tried hard-coding it right when I call the line `$extend.Cells.Item($modifyCell.Cells.Row) = "Y"` and it works as it should. So how I'm trying to use regex to pull the username is likely not right. Probably how I'm pulling the data as well.